# Deserialize JSON with vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, api, zoho

This is my manually created class

```
Public Class ZohoList
    Public Property Select_Store() As String
        Get
            Return m_Select_Store
        End Get
        Set
            m_Select_Store = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Select_Store As String
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property Zoho_List As List(Of ZohoList)
        Get
            Return m_Zoho_List
        End Get
        Set
            m_Zoho_List = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Zoho_List As List(Of ZohoList)
End Class
```

After i get JSON response like this

```
{
   "Store_Money_Snapshot":[
      {
         "TODO":"YES",
         "Date_field":"10-May-2018",
         "Xpawn_Money":"3562",
         "Select_Store":"TEST",
         "Total_Counted_Money":"$ 3,000.00",
         "Store_from_Xpawn_pc2":"TEST",
         "Discrepancy_Amount":"$ -562.00",
         "Store_Problem_fixed":"NO",
         "ID":"1111111111111111111",
         "Image":"",
         "Store_Closing_Balance":"$ 33,482.00"
      },
      {
         "TODO":"YES",
         "Date_field":"10-May-2018",
         "Xpawn_Money":"10234",
         "Select_Store":"TEST2",
         "Total_Counted_Money":"$ 9,800.00",
         "Store_from_Xpawn_pc2":"TEST2",
         "Discrepancy_Amount":"$ -434.00",
         "Store_Problem_fixed":"NO",
         "ID":"2222222222222",
         "Image":"",
         "Store_Closing_Balance":"$ 33,482.00"
      }
   ]
}
```

My vb.net code for deserializing object is put in two lines

```
Dim myO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(response)
            Dim items = myO.Zoho_List

            For Each item In items
                lTodo.Add(item.Select_Store.ToString)
                'Now comes th code
            Next
```

From entire response i only need the Select_Store value so in class i put only that value

Also i tried put all values in my class but still it wont deserialize JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RootObject` is paired with the first curly brace `{`.

There is then one property on that "root object' in the json: `Store_Money_Snapshot`, which doesn't appear anywhere in your `RootObject`.
`Store_Money_Snapshot` is an array or `List<>` or objects.  These objects contain your `Select_Store` property.

So something like this should get you moving:

```
Public Class RootObject
  '  RootObject is a HORRIBLE name.

    Public Property Store_Money_Snapshot As List(Of ZohoList)

End Class

Public Class ZohoList
  '  Again, ZohoList is a HORRIBLE name.

    Public Property Select_Store As String
End Class
```

I strongly encourage you to give some thought to naming your classes with more accurate descriptive names.

Comment: I cant belive it that was so simple. I strongly agree about naming those classes.   So the class ZohoList is actually - oneStore and RootObject is - Stores :)

Comment: You got it.  Have fun with your project.